# Is there a way to turn off the focus point display on a D7000 when a manual lens is mounted?

Tags: nikon-d7000, manual-focus, focusing-screen

I recently got a [Katzeye](http://katzeyeoptics.com/) focusing screen for my D7000. Since my favorite lenses are all manual focus, I'm really enjoying this.

Unfortunately, my D7000 helpfully puts a focus point on the focusing screen. When I have the center focus point selected, this is right in the middle of my split-screen pellicle:

[image: A cell phone camera shot through my viewfinder]

This makes it more difficult to use the focusing pellicle - a surprising amount of detail can be hidden by that focus point. I can move it off-center, but then it becomes distracting - a little off-center spot that draws my eye.

Is there a way to turn the focus point display off entirely, or have it turn off when I have a manual focus lens attached?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the Custom Settings menu and set option A4 (*AF Point Illumination*) to off.

Comment: As mentioned, it's A4 for autofocus point display and, since your screenshot included it, option D2 will toggle the Viewfinder Grid Display.

Comment: This just seems to prevent the red LED which lights up the AF points from illuminating -- it does nothing to keep the point from being there in the first place.